# pinvoke return a float

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

have been working on this for hours, couldn't get it work :(

below code gives exception *"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."* **this is fixed, see below update**

but when i change the return type to **int** and return a **int** value, it works. how to make it to return a **float** value? thanks.

vs2012

c++ code

```
extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)
float compute_similarity()
{       
    return 1.01;
}
```

c# code

```
[DllImport("demo.exe", EntryPoint = "compute_similarity", CallingConvention =  CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern float compute_similarity();

public void Get()
{
  float x = compute_similarity(); // here returns random value
}
```

=====================================

**UPDATE**

See comments from David below, the problem was the c# project is targeting x64 and c++ is targeting Win32. After changing the c# project to target to x86, the exception went away.

**However the call from c# returns some random value instead of 1.01 expected**

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit machine? I'm just wondering whether the C code returns a 64 bit "float" (ie a double for the C# code) if it is a 64 bit environment.

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly add `__cdecl` between `float` and `compute_similarity` in C++?

Comment: @DavidArno thanks a lot David, yes c# project is targeting x64 and c++ is targeting Win32, after changing c# project to target x86, it made the exception go away although it still returns some random value instead of 1.01 expected. Updated the question.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `CallingConvention.StdCall`?

Comment: When you say random, is it near what you expected or something else? Example return values would help.

Comment: That should work fine (but demo should be a .dll, not an .exe). Or post your project somewhere so we can dig more.

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard most of time returns 0.0, sometimes return values like -6.4284847310593848E-40. thx

Comment: Try making the return value const and adding f to the end like so: float compute_similarity() const { return 1.01f; }

Comment: @MatthewWatson Default C++ calling convention is `cdecl`. So, not the C# should not be using `stdcall`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True - but that's the *default*, and perhaps the C++ module is compiled with `/Gz`. Maybe the safest thing to do when exporting C/C++ methods is to explicitly mark them with `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`.

Comment: @Xin What happens if you change the `C` declaration to include `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall` and change the PInvoke to specify `CallingConvention.StdCall` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Odds are very high that the C++ module is not compiled with `/Gz`. Yes, explicitly stating calling convention is best. But suggesting `stdcall` is probably not helpful. Also, for a function with no parameters, `stdcall` and `cdecl` are the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Very true. It's an odd thing - the OP's code should work. I don't suppose there's any way that the C++ compiler is enregistering the return value? That would have an untoward effect. I'm pretty sure that's not default behaviour though (and is incompatible with DLLExport in any case).

Comment: @MatthewWatson The only error I can see is the use of an exe rather than a dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that your function is declared in an executable rather than a DLL. Convert your native code into a library project and compile a DLL.

Your code will result in a call to `LoadLibrary` passing the file name `demo.exe`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175.aspx) for `LoadLibrary` says:

> `LoadLibrary` can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file to get a handle that can be used in `FindResource` or `LoadResource`. However, do not use `LoadLibrary` to run an .exe file. Instead, use the `CreateProcess` function.

And so your code is doing exactly what you are told not to do. The call to `LoadLibrary` will succeed. The subsequent calls to `GetProcAddress` will succeed. But the module that you loaded is not fit to execute code.

Comment: It seems plausible, but on the other hand Microsoft say that it's ok to P/Invoke into exes (see the response from a Microsoft employee [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e5eab264-6ce8-4c60-ac6d-2b4cf37a5a8c/pinvoke-into-hosting-executable?forum=clr) - still, it seems worth a try!

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's fine if the module is already loaded. But the code in the question will call `LoadLibrary` on the executable. That is documented as not working: *LoadLibrary can also be used to load other executable modules. For example, the function can specify an .exe file to get a handle that can be used in FindResource or LoadResource. However, do not use LoadLibrary to run an .exe file. Instead, use the CreateProcess function.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, MatthewWaston thanks for all your inputs. changing it to dll output did fix it. although not sure why this made a difference.

Comment: @Xin It makes a difference because calling `LoadLibrary` on an executable file does not return a module handle that is valid to execute code. That's documented by the italicised quote in my comment above that is extracted from the MSDN docs for `LoadLibrary`.